# In JavaScript, how do you find out the container object of a number field?

Tags: javascript, performance, hash

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};
function parent_object(num){
    console.log('This number is inside the object ',<????>);
}
parent_object(obj.a)
```

This should output pointing to obj. The only way I found to do this is boxing every number object in an object which would keep a reference to the parent. This is, though, a performance killer. Is there a better way of keeping track of the location of a number?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: This is impossible as described.

Comment: numbers in JavaScript are actually "primitives" .. so while this can be done by decorating Objects (including those of Number, although I am not aware what optimizations an implementation is allowed to make), it is never feasible for "primitive" numbers.

Comment: Platinum, this is explained in my last question, I'm open for suggestions!

Comment: @Dokkat Please re-summarize and make each question "self sufficient". (Also, without a link to said "last question", we have no idea what transpired.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually no. And not only in JavaScript, but in none of the other conventional languages.

As far as I know, the only way would be for you to do exactly what you yourself said: boxing the number (or any other field type) in an object that would keep a reference (maybe by constructor injection) to its enclosing parent.

The boxing in question can be thus accomplished:

```
BoxedValue = function(value, parent) {
    this.value = value;
    this.parent = parent;
}

var i = {};
n.i = new BoxedValue(12, i)
console.log(i.n.parent);
```

However, generally speaking, the most important factor in your JavaScript application's performance for current browsers is the way you handle your memory usage. Therefore, this approach isn't really advisable, and I suggest you solve your problem, whatever it might be, via some other method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, because you can have objects reference each other from multiple places:

```
var num = 1;
var obj = {a: num, b: 2};
var obj2 = {x: num};

parent_object(obj.a);    // should it return obj or obj2? Both are technically correct!
```

What are you really trying to solve here? There is probably a better approach available to you.

Comment: It would not happen on my specific case, as every object would have a fixed location inside a big hash tree. But you are right. This is what I am trying to solve: I have a system where everything is part of a big tree, so it must keep track of it's parent. Only numbers and strings can't, because you can't set 3.parent, for example.

Comment: Create a new object type where the value and the parent are kept track of, and make sure your tree only consists of that object type.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {a:1,b:'string',c:2} 
for(prop in obj){
  if(typeof obj[prop]=='number'){
    console.log(prop + ' : ' + obj[prop] + ' found')
  }
}
```

logs:

a : 1 found

c : 2 found

Comment: This tests for a value in an object, not which object the value is in .. don't ask me why the question is what it is.

Comment: I have explained that on my last question if you are interested.

Comment: This does not accomplish what the question is aiming at.